# Find the flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z)=z\vec{k}$ across the outward oriented sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the flux of the vector field $F(x,y,z)=z\vec{k}$ across the outward oriented sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$

$G(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-a^2=0$ hence $\nabla G=⟨2x,2y,2z⟩$ and $F.\nabla G=2z^2=2(a^2-x^2-y^2)$
\begin{align}
\int\int_\sigma F.N\:dS&=\int\int_R F.\nabla G\:dA\\
&=2\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} (a^2-x^2-y^2)dydx\\
&=2\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^a\left(a^2-r^2\right)rdrd\theta\\ 
&=\pi a^4
\end{align}
But if I use parametrization $$r(\phi,\theta)=a\sin\phi\cos\theta\vec{i}+a\sin\phi\sin\theta\vec{j}+a\cos\phi\vec{k}\quad (0\leq\phi\leq\pi,0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi)$$ $$F.\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} \right)=a^3\sin\phi\cos^2\phi$$
\begin{align}
\int\int_\sigma F.N\:dS&=\int\int_R F.\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} \right)\:dA\\
&=\frac{4\pi a^3}{3}
\end{align}
I knew that my second approach give the correct answer but I was wondering why the first approach give me wrong answer$?$ Am I doing it wrongly or missing something$?$
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first calculation contains three errors. First, $\mathrm dA$ is not $\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$. You're missing the factor $\frac az$ in $\mathrm dA$ that accounts for the slope of the surface. Second, you need to normalize the outward normal vector, which divides it by a factor of $2a$. Third, you're only calculating the result for the upper hemisphere; adding the identical result for the lower hemisphere yields a factor of $2$.

The second calculation also contains an error, I'm not sure how you got the correct result out of it. The dimensions in $F\cdot\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial \phi}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \theta} \right)\mathrm dA$ are wrong – you're integrating $F$ over an area, so the result should have the dimensions of $F$ times length squared, but here you have the dimensions of $F$ times length to the fourth. Instead of $\mathrm dA$ you need $\mathrm d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta$. If you substitute that, the result comes out right.

In any case, you don't really need all this integration stuff. In three dimensions, the sphere has the special property that slices of equal height have equal surface areas. So you just need to average $F\cdot\frac{\nabla G}{|\nabla G|}=\frac{z^2}a$ over $z$ from $-a$ to $a$, yielding $\frac a3$, and multiply by the total surface are $4\pi a^2$ of the sphere.

Comment: **You're missing the factor $\frac{a}{z}$ in dA** I didn't get that. I just project the surface in xy-plane then why any change happen in $dA?$ and yes I forgot about normalization thanks @joriki .I just use your telling and find the correct result but still confused why  factor $\frac{a}{z}$ used.

Comment: @Dr.Antidode: That's exactly the problem, you're projecting the surface into the $xy$-plane. Imagine looking down along the $z$ direction onto the sphere and the $xy$ plane. The surface near the pole is orthogonal to your line of sight, and visible at scale, whereas the surface near the equator is barely visible to you in this projection.

Comment: @Dr.Antidode: Mathematically speaking, you can obtain this factor just like you got the right factor in the second approach, from

$$
\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \right)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\;,
$$

where you're now parametrizing $r$ as $r(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2})$.

Comment: Is $\partial r$ should be $\partial z?$ @joriki

Comment: @Dr.Antidode: No, why? It's exactly the same principle as in the second approach: You calculate the area element $\mathrm dS$ in terms of the parameter volume element $\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ by taking the cross product of the rates at which the position vector $r$ varies with the parameters.

Comment: I am confusing. $\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \right)dxdy$ what is $r$ represent here$?$ @joriki

Comment: @Dr.Antidode: Sorry, I edited that into the comment after I submitted it. You should be able to see it if you reload. It represents the position vector in exactly the same way as in your second approach. (I just wrote it as a triple of coordinates instead of your notation with $\vec i$, $\vec j$, $\vec k$.)

Comment: Thanks @joriki and thanks also tolerating me